# integrate a binomial raised to a fractional power

Tags: integration

I need to integrate (with respect to r): A,B,C can be seen as constant for these purposes.

$$\left( -{r}^{2}B+3\,A \right) ^{3/2\,{\frac {{\it AC}}{{B}^{2}}}}$$

I see so far my options being Taylors Series or a Binomial expansion with a fractional power and then integrate the result but are there any other approaches I might take?
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: With just plain $3/2$ in the exponent this can be done by parts, ending with an $\arcsin$. With the $AC/B^2$ there I think you will need power series.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=\frac {3 AC}{3B^2}$ to face
$$I=\int \left( -{r}^{2}B+3\,A \right) ^a\,dr$$
Let $r=\sqrt{\frac {3A} B} \sqrt{x}$ to make
$$I=\frac 12 (3A)^a\sqrt{\frac {3A} B}\int \frac{(1-x)^a}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx$$ and
$$J=\int \frac{(1-x)^a}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx=2 \sqrt{x} \,\, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},-a;\frac{3}{2};x\right)$$ where appears the gaussian hypergeometric function which is not the most pleasant result.

For sure,  you could use the infinite expansion $$\, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},-a;\frac{3}{2};x\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma (n-a)}{(2 n+1) \Gamma (-a) \Gamma (n+1)}x^n$$

Comment: thanks very much for your help! I will investigate this transformation and function